# Error: The Remote Server Machine Does Not Exist or is Unavailable (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I looked at similar questions' answers and could not find that were applicable to what I am trying to do.

Here is some code that loads an instance of IE , goes to Apple's financials, and attempts to scrape the table on that webpage.

The error happens on Set IEDocument = IEObject.document

```
Sub ScrapeTable2()

Dim IEObject As InternetExplorer

Set IEObject = New InternetExplorer

IEObject.Visible = True

IEObject.navigate URL:="https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL"

Debug.Print IEObject.LocationURL

Dim IEDocument As HTMLDocument
Set IEDocument = IEObject.document

Dim IETables As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim IETable As IHTMLTable
Dim IERow As IHTMLTableRow
Dim IECell As IHTMLTableCell

Set IETable = IEDocument.getElementsByTagName("table")

RowCount = 1

max_rows = IETable.Rows.Length

For Each IERow In IETable.Rows
    Debug.Print IERow.innerText
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: This https://www.reddit.com/r/vba/comments/db91iu/vba_runtime_error462_remote_server_machine_does/ suggests using `set ieobject = createobject("internetexplorer.application")` Regardless, this is a bad way to do web scraping. There are a lot of VBA stock web scraping comments on SO right now. What's the story?

Comment: You're not waiting for the page to load after calling `Navigate`

Comment: I am still getting the same message, this time on the Do Loop calling for it  to wait.

Comment: ```
Do While IEObject.Busy = True Or IEObject.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
Loop
```

The ready state complete is in the same line as the Do Loop, any thoughts?